# Why do we sing while saying viduy?

Tags: yom-kippur

Throughout Yom Kippur everyone says viduy (confession) numerous times.
In the shuls that I have davened at (and I think most shuls), when everyone says it together during *chazaras hashatz*, there is a little niggun that is sung between phrases (after דברנו דופי, טפלנו שקר, etc.).
Viduy is the time when we say how we sinned in many different ways; why are we singing during this time?

Comment: Surely it's dependent on the tune? We lein Eicha in a mournful tune which is appropriate to the day? Likewise, here - it is not a jolly, happy-clappy moment?!